# How to redirect from a link to another?

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

If I'm on this link `website.com/index.php?id=19` I want that if you try to remove the `?id=..` so the link will just be `website.com/index.php` the user will be redirected to `website.com/index.php?id=..`
How do I do that?

Comment: In such case I use url token so that user don't play with url or query string. `url?token={token value}` you can store key value in token which is encrypted to determine which action you need to perform.

Comment: Thanks man,will look it up how it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `header` and `$_GET` - for example:

```php
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id'])) {
   header('Location: /index.php?id=155');
   exit();
}
```

Where `155` is whatever you want there to be.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']))
{
   header('location:index.php?id=here is your id value');
   exit;
}
```